# Build test code as a library or as an executable?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd

In unit-testing and test driven development, why is it better to build test code as a library rather than as an executable for testing a c++ program?  I have heard arguments for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a separate executable for your test code and run it as a post-build event of your main application. This way, if the tests fail, the build fails. Most C++ IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio, Eclipse, QtCreator) support this.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for library vs executable depend on how you want your developers to use the tests.

If you want to have the tests integrated into the build process, you probably want a command-line executable.  If you want to have the tests runnable from some kind of standalone GUI app, you might want a window based executable.  If you want the tests to be run by a metrics gathering server, they may need to be hosted in a service.

If you want more than one of these methods, you could choose to compile the tests into a library, then link them into each of the executable frameworks.  But if you only ever have need of command-line execution, then there'd be no need for the GUI or service options, and no advantage gained from building a separate static library.

Neither approach is "better".  Choose the approach you need based on your team's particular situation, and your team's standards.  It's also probably not that important right now.  If you start with just an executable test harness, you can always split the tests into a static library later.

It's far more important that you start writing and running automated testing now than to pause and quibble about the test implementation details.